# Vue.js - Declare props and data fields in mixins

Tags: vue.js

Is it a bad practice to declare commonly used props and data fields in mixins? If no, is there any name convention for them (e.g. `$_myMixin_myDataField`)?

Comment: I think so that is a good practice! `Vue.mixin({ ... })`! use like global;

Answer (score 2):

Since vue mixins are especially designed for sharing logic and making components more reusable I would recommend declaring commonly used props and data fields in mixins. I haven't found any naming conventions for mixins props and data fields in [Vue's Style Guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/) so I think you might be fine choosing some intuitive names as always for your fields.
Moreover I would not suggest using a global mixin in order to declare props and data. Props should only exist when they're required for that component, if you declare them globally the would be used on components which actually don't need them. Same with data, this would lead to a huge amount of unused data fields